# Access request user and url parameters in django decorator

Tags: python, django, decorator, python-decorators

I am trying to eliminate redundant code by creating a decorator to handle simple logic that is always repeated. Basically every view I create has the following logic to check if a user is in a class.

```
@login_required
def view(request, class_id):

    class_ = UserClasses.objects.get(user=request.user, class_id=class_id)

    # if the user is in the class
    if class_:
```

I'd like to do the following:

View:

```
@user_passes_test(in_class(request.user, class_id))
@login_required
def view(request, class_id):
```

Decorator:

```
from apps.classes.models import UserClasses

def in_class(request, class_id):
    class_ = UserClasses.objects.get(user=request.user, class_id=class_id)
    if class_:
        return true
    else:
        return false
```

What's the best way to go about achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your decorator should be like this

```
def user_passes_test(old_fuction):
    def new_function(request, class_id, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            class_ = UserClasses.objects.get(user=request.user, class_id=class_id)
        except Exception as e:
            return HttpResponse('ERROR: User not present in the class')
        return old_fuction(request, class_id, *args, **kwargs)
    return new_function
```

If the `UserClasses` contains row with both `user` and `class_id`(assumes that `user` is `unique`), the view function will be executed.Otherwise it will return an Error response(ERROR: User not present in the class).

And you view function should be

```
@user_passes_test
@login_required
def view(request, class_id):
```

if you want the `class_` object in the view function, you can do it by simple changes. modify your decorator like

```
def user_passes_test(old_fuction):
    def new_function(request, class_id, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            class_ = UserClasses.objects.get(user=request.user, class_id=class_id)
        except Exception as e:
            return HttpResponse('ERROR: User not present in the class')
        return old_fuction(request, class_id, class_, *args, **kwargs)
    return new_function
```

And the view function should be

```
@user_passes_test
@login_required
def view(request, class_id, class_obj):
```

where `class_obj` contains the `class_` object

Comment: A bit late to this but in case anyone is hitting an issue - in the except block the syntax is 'except Exception as e:'